# Redirect to foreign page by embedding request

Tags: java, servlets

How to call/redirect to the foreign page by embedding request object from the servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. You need the [response](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29) object.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://google.com");
```